# Vacuum analyze is running very slow and causes timeouts for other systems

Tags: .net, postgresql

I'm running PostgresSQL 8.3.3. Every night a vacuum analyze is performed against the database. Every table takes around 5 minutes to complete (large or small). Initially the process took 1/3 of the time it does now. While the vacuum is performed other data is still being inserted through a .net windows service. This service started logging connection timeouts recently.

Is there a way of figuring out what is causing the slow running of the vacuum analyze and/or what is causing the timeouts? I suspect they are related.

Comment: Is autovacuum running? What's `vacuum_cost_delay` set to? **Why are you still on 8.3.3**? (+1 mentioned PostgreSQL version, though).

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html

Comment: Autovacuum is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, version 8.3 is end-of-life, so you'll want to upgrade as soon as is convenient anyway.

That version does support autovacuum, as far as I can see from the documentation and if configured correctly that should tend to keep things under control. However, it's possible that bursty activity and/or index bloat has caused you some problems.

The simplest solution is to dump the database and restore. If you can afford the time to do so, it will pack the whole database in that process. Then, put in some regular (daily/weekly) monitoring of table/index sizes. Also add some basic monitoring of general activity on the machine (cpu / memory / disk).

You can take corrective action with a [REINDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-vacuum.html) or [CLUSTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-cluster.html) if it's required.

If you run [VACUUM VERBOSE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-vacuum.html) on one table at a time you'll see some statistics on what disk pages are used / can be freed / can't be freed. It should be obvious if there is a problem.

Finally, do take the time to plan an upgrade at a convenient point. The latest release is 9.2 and contains many performance and management improvements.

Comment: 8.3's autovacuum is pretty primitive and often needed help from extra vacuum cron jobs to keep up. Also, they're not just on 8.3, they're on an ancient patch-release of 8.3 that's years and many fixes out-of-date.

Comment: I will try a back- and restore like you suggest tonight. I will keep you posted if that fixes the issue. An upgrade is scheduled for this summer.

Comment: Remember - check to check file sizes and system load this afternoon so you've got something to compare against after the restore.

Comment: OK - so your vacuum settings need to be increased, and consider occasional reindexes (monitor and see which indexes if any). Probably not worth doing if you're going to upgrade shortly - the vacuum system has had a lot of work on it since 8.3